# Using ngstorage for persistent data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-storage

I know that there are solutions  to how to use ngstorage in our applications to have persistent data available even after refresh. I tried implementing it for the first time in my form today. But unable to figure out where I am going wrong. Can someone please let me know where I am going wrong? Also, I am looking to have the persistent functionality on adding and deleting the data.

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngStorage'])
  .controller('AppController', ['$scope', '$localStorage',
    '$sessionStorage',
    function($scope,$localStorage,$sessionStorage) {
      var self = this;

      self.$storage = $localStorage;

      self.user = {
        id: null,
        username: '',
        address: '',
        email: ''
      };
      self.id = 4;

      self.users = [{
        id: 1,
        email: 'sam@tarly.com',
        firstname: 'Sam',
        lastname: 'Tarly',
        telephone: 1234567890,
        address: 'NY',

      }, {
        id: 2,
        email: 'jon@snow.com',
        firstname: 'Jon',
        lastname: 'Snow',
        telephone: 9876543210,
        address: 'The Wall',
      }, {
        id: 3,
        email: 'dany@targaryen.com',
        firstname: 'Dany',
        lastname: 'Targaryen',
        telephone: 1234987650,
        address: 'NEBRASKA'
      }];

      self.submit = function() {
        if (self.user.id === null) {
          self.user.id = self.id++;
          alert('Added New User', self.user);
          self.users.push(self.user); 
          $localStorage.users = self.users;
        } else {
          for (var i = 0; i < self.users.length; i++) {
            if (self.users[i].id === self.user.id) {
              self.users[i] = self.user;
              break;
            }
          }
          alert('User updated with id ', self.user.id);
        }
        self.reset();
      };

      self.edit = function(id) {
        alert('id to be edited', id);
        for (var i = 0; i < self.users.length; i++) {
          if (self.users[i].id === id) {
            self.user = angular.copy(self.users[i]);
            break;
          }
        }
      };

      self.remove = function(id) {
        alert('id to be deleted', id);
        for (var i = 0; i < self.users.length; i++) {
          if (self.users[i].id === id) {
            self.users.splice(i, 1);
            $localStorage.users = self.users;
            if (self.user.id === id) { //It is shown in form, reset it.
              self.reset();
            }
            break;
          }
        }
      };

      self.reset = function() {
        self.user = {
          id: null,
          username: '',
          address: '',
          email: ''
        };
        $scope.myForm.$setPristine(); //reset Form
      };

    }
    ]);
```

[Plnkr Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/7J6xj7canR4UOJoOnjGR?p=preview)

Comment: are you having trouble to show the added value when you refresh the page?

Comment: yes. The value adds up or deletes normally. But when I reload the page, the values are not seen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding, for you the issue is the value not shown in table after adding the data and refreshing the page. The problem is you are initially loading the data with static array value. The data is infact added to storage. You just have to call the initial loading from `$localStorage`. Just change the `self.users = [{..}]` to  `self.users = $localStorage.users`. I have updated the plunkr. Please take a look at it.

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/W9qG8f6PkbcW9MqT10PF?p=preview)

Comment: Nope its not working. Shows the alert box but does not add the data to the list below.

Comment: @ross: let me check

Comment: Please take a look at this @ross: http://plnkr.co/edit/W9qG8f6PkbcW9MqT10PF?p=preview

Comment: Yes it works. However, the id is not updated at all and stays at 4. Also, would like to add,update,delete by having the alert box say that particular username to be deleted.

Comment: @ross: Please take a look at this plunkr. http://plnkr.co/edit/q9vo01toTb8zwFZWm1zD?p=preview